# Data comparison between two dataframe and list mismatched rows seperately using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes with same columns and different rows. Need suggestion to compare and show the result as given way.
df1 :

[image]

df2 :

[image]

Expected result is missing rows and mismatched rows with difference values.

df_ouput1: Mismatched row values with columns
[image]

df2_output : Missing rows from the df2 side to checking df1:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge two dataframes and apply new column with boolean value if row not matches.
Filter as we required in the column.

[image: Code]
[image: Result]